# Magento 2 php bin/magento setup:install WITHOUT sample data

Tags: magento2

As the Title says I'm trying to run php `bin/magento setup:install` without the sample sample data (Products and all).

There is an option to this command `--use-sample-data`  I've tried it with `--use-sample-data=no` and I got --use-sample-data takes no arguments.

I've tried it without the --use-sample-data flag and still products were added.

To be more specific about what I'm trying to achieve here.

I have a magento installation with custom extensions as well.

I wish to achieve a clean db (as clean as it can be).

Any tips are highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.

Because I previously installed Magento2 with sample data there was information added to my composer.json that caused sample data to be installed at each new php bin/magento setup:install even though no --use-sample-data flag was given.

To fix it I did the following:

1. php bin/magento sampledata:remove.
2. php bin/magento setup:install --with-associated-params